# Pycharm: "Cannot find reference 'load' in 'image.py'"

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I have a problem I'm working in Pycharm with Pygames and when I try to pygame.image.load() it doesn't work and keep telling me that it cannot find 'load' in image.py. I redownloaded the pygame package and it still doesn't work. Please help me.

Pycharm reports: `Cannot find reference 'load' in 'image.py'`, when using `pygame.image.load()`. The code breaks when trying to execute this command.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 720))
my_image = pygame.image.load('maxresdefault.bmp')

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    surface.fill((188, 22, 22)
    surface.blit(my_image, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

After redownloading the Pygame package, the issue persists.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/126mj.png)

[Error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL6Is.png)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code and error messages as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Pycharm mistakenly warns that `pygame.image.load` cannot be found, but it can. Try loading a png image instead, because pygame can only load a limited amount of formats.

Comment: After looking through the image.py code in Pycharm, I've found that it imports `load()` from another file: `from pygame.imageext import load, load_extended, save_extended`. There is no method named `load`in imageext.py, at least not one that Pycharm shows. [Pygame.image](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html)

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm seems to have problems referencing `load` but it works fine. There are 2 separate issues here: The `load` error (which can be ignored as there doesn't seem to be any way around it, and PyGame works just fine), but secondly, and more importantly, there is a problem with your image file itself. Is it in the same directory as your script? `.bmp` is the standard format so that shouldn't be an issue. If it's in the right directory, and the name is correct, try converting it to a `.png` or `.jpg` image.